# OpenGL usage on mobile HTML5 games

Tags: html, mobile, webgl, jscript

I have an HTML5 game running in desktop web browsers using WebGL. Obviously HTML5 and jscript can be built out to the mobile platform, but then what happens to the WebGL code?

I assume WebGL doesn't work very well in mobile apps.

Then how do you use OpenGL in mobile HTML5? Is there a jscript binding to OpenGL ES?

Thanks

EDIT: Just to be clear I am talking about native installed mobile apps not browsers. As in using something like PhoneGap

Comment: Check http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl for browser support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume WebGL doesn't work very well in mobile apps.

What does you make think this? WebGL has been based on OpenGL-ES 2.0, which is the OpenGL-ES profile supported by most mobile devices out there. So WebGL maps nicely to mobile devices' GPU capabilities. It's more a question of browser suppport, than performance.

Comment: About your EDIT with natively installed apps. Those usually use OpenGL-ES directly, not WebGL.

Comment: To extend your response: WebGL is a Subset of OpenGL ES 2.0... so it's only a matter of support and javascript performance. Firefox on Android supports WebGL and it runs rather slowly, but that's because most matrix transforms are done via Javascript which is rather slow on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Nicol,
appMobi has integrated WebGL into its iOS and Android native wrappers, giving roughly 10x performance boost for HTML5 canvas drawing. appMobi is similar to PhoneGap, in building a native "wrapper" that your HTML5 lives inside, with a JS API that lets your game access all of the operating system functions. Here's a page describing the acceleration, which we call directCanvas. http://www.appmobi.com/index.php?q=content/directcanvas-accelerates-html5-game-performance

Hope this is helpful!
Roy